# Populate an HTML table with characters from String Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I need to create a 2*50 cell table and populate it with string literal pre-stored in a JavaScript array.

I have stored the string in an array and created a table. I am unable to populate it.

```
 //string literal pre-stored in a javascipt array
 var proverbs = ["Love sees no faults", "friend in need is a friend indeed"];
 var txt= proverbs[0];

 document.write('<table id= "tab" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="30">')
 for(i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    document.write('<tr>')
    document.write('<td>')
    document.write('<td>')
    document.write('</tr>')
 }

 for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
   tab +=  document.write("<tr><td>" + txt[i] + "</td></tr>");
 } 

 document.write('</table>')
```

This does not work. Ho w do I now populate the table. The last for loop I wrote is to fill up the table cells, one char per cell. Can anyone tell how do I implement it.

Comment: *"This does not work."* - What does it do? Something else? Nothing? Any errors in the brower's console? (Hints: where have you defined the `tab` variable? You *use* it but don't declare or initialise it. What is the `txt` variable for - just use `proverbs` directly.)

Comment: for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
   tab +=  "<tr><td>" + txt[i] + "</td>";
 } .... this does not populate the table. There is no error anywhere. But the table is still blank.

Comment: If you write HTML tags with `document.write(…)` or insert them with `innerHTML` and you don’t close these tags then they will be closed automatically. I. e. `document.write('<table …>')` will produce `<table …></table>` with no content in it. Instead put all your markup in a string and only _then_ write it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it's missing a few things.

1st problem:
 var proverbs = ["Love sees no faults", "friend in need is a friend indeed"];
 var txt= proverbs[0];

You assign proverbs sub 0 to txt. That's fine, the value of txt is now "Love sees no faults". But, later you reference txt[i].

2nd problem

```
for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
  tab +=  "<tr><td>" + txt[i] + "</td>";
}
```

you don't close the tr tag. But then also you don't do anything with tab.

I think you are printing an empty table.

Comment: I closed the row. My question is how do I populate the table.